# TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable - Python - OpenErp

Tags: python, function, orm, odoo

I'm trying to read a field inside an object from another class from the one having this function in openerp:

```
def desc_cert(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, field_args, context=None):
    obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')
    pids = obj.search(cr, uid [('sel_cert', '=', 'si')])
    val = self._get_product_available_func(('done'))
    if pids == 'si':
            return val
```

Being `sel_cert` the field in the class i'm trying to read from `self.pool.get`, i'm still learning OpenErp but this code gives me the error you see in the title of this post, here's the traceback:

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 197, in execute
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 3604, in read
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 3724, in _read_flat
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\fields.py", line 1133, in get
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\openerp\addons\product\product.py", line 456, in desc_cert
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

I can't understand what is wrong with the code, i already saw a very similar example in the `account` module, what i'm trying to achieve is to read the field `sel_cert` from `purchase.order` object, which is a `selection` type field, so if this field has `si` selected then do `_get_product_available_func(('done'))`

Just for verbosity sakes :)

So, anybody could shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the type of `uid` ?

Comment: getting the same error ..... any solution???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are missing a comma after `uid` in that line.

Comment: True... sorry, let me check

Comment: Yes, it was that, now i get another error :(, edited my question

Comment: That doesn't seem to relate to any of the code you've posted. Perhaps you should ask a new question and post the relevant code there.

Comment: Yes, i thought so, because it's a completely different problem, i'll do it right now!, thank you very much!